# Is RegExp.MatchString thread-safe?

Tags: go

Is https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.MatchString thread-safe if I run `regexp.MustCompile("")` on it in http-request goutines? I'm not modifying the compile on the instance after the first compile.

I'm just wondering if it's compatible on read-time too or if I should apply some form of mutex locking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the source file of [regexp.go](https://golang.org/src/regexp/regexp.go)

> A Regexp is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines, 
>   except for configuration methods, such as Longest.

So, yeah, they are thread-safe.

Comment: It’s not just hidden in the source, it’s in the documentation https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp